# How to move bits of a number from register to eight other registers

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, avr

I’m trying to move bits from starting register into eight consecutive registers. I’ve just started writing in assembly so I dont really know what to do.

I tried to use rol and lsr instructions. But my loop just reverses the bits. can i change the registry from r18 to r19 mid-loop?

```
.equ sequen = 0x10001011

ldi r17 
ldi r16, 0x8

next: lsr r17
rol r18    

             ;is there a way to move  
            ;to next register, not    
            ; inc its value?
dec r16
brbc 1, next
rjmp pc
```

Comment: On most ISAs you couldn't use a loop, because registers aren't wouldn't be indexable.  So you'd need a different machine-code instruction to write a different register.  But on AVR they do have addresses: the registers are mapped to the low 32 bytes of data-memory address space.

Comment: If you were to attempt this on a different architecture, the only way to "move to the next register" would be to first store all the registers' value in memory and iterate over that memory.

Comment: On different architectures is possible make self modification code to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As say Peter Cordes it is possible. For example like this

```
.equ sequen = 0b1000_1011

        ldi r17, sequen
        ldi r16, 0x8

        ldi zl,18     ;Z (ZH:ZL) is used as indirect address register (pointer in C terminology)
        ldi zh,0      ;this two instruction set Z to 18 - address for first value. See AVR memmory map for details
        clr r0        
next:
        bst r17,0   
        bld r0, 0
        st  z+, r0    ;save result to register and increase address (18, 19, ...|
        lsr r17
        dec r16
        brne next
        rjmp pc
```

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a way to set a register according to an arbitrary status bit, so you could use the bit shifted out by `lsr`.  (into the carry flag).  There is `sbc r8,r8` but that sets it to `0` or `-1` (same-same - carry), rather than `0` or `1`, and one extra instruction to negate it would make it no cheaper than `bst`/`bld` or `mov`/`andi`.  And two stores (of 0 and 1) with an `sbis` or `brcs` to skip one would be clunky and probably slower.

Comment: This seems to do the job, but i dont think i really get what „ldi xl, 18” and „ldi xh, 0” does

Comment: Yes, this code cover your picture. I test it by AVR studio simulator. What is unclear?

Comment: @Samsen12: Do you mean loading `zl` / `zh`?  AVR accesses memory through 16-bit pointer registers that are actually a pair of 8-bit registers.  Those two instructions set Z = 18, the address where `r18` is mapped.  After that, incrementing Z (as part of the `st` instruction) will access the memory-mapped location of `r19` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to move bits from starting register into eight consecutive registers.

Just un-roll that loop:

```
lsr r17 $ clr r18 $ rol r18
lsr r17 $ clr r19 $ rol r19
lsr r17 $ clr r20 $ rol r20
lsr r17 $ clr r21 $ rol r21
lsr r17 $ clr r22 $ rol r22
lsr r17 $ clr r23 $ rol r23
lsr r17 $ clr r24 $ rol r24
lsr r17 $ clr r25 $ rol r25
```

`$` is a line separator supported by GNU assembler.

Alternatively, you can store the respective bit in the T flag and then load it to the target register.  Advantage is that you don't destroy r17:

```
bst r17,0 $ clr r18 $ bld r18,0
bst r17,1 $ clr r19 $ bld r19,0
bst r17,2 $ clr r20 $ bld r20,0
bst r17,3 $ clr r21 $ bld r21,0
bst r17,4 $ clr r22 $ bld r22,0
bst r17,5 $ clr r23 $ bld r23,0
bst r17,6 $ clr r24 $ bld r24,0
bst r17,7 $ clr r25 $ bld r25,0
```

Yet another way is to skip depending on r17 value, which also consumes 3 instructions per bit:

```
clr  r18
sbrc r17, 0
inc  r18
clr  r19
sbrc r17, 1
inc  r19
clr  r20
sbrc r17, 2
inc  r20
...
```

The GNU assembler allows to write this as a repetition that expands to 24 instructions:

```
    .irp reg, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
    lsr r17
    clr 18+\reg
    rol 18+\reg
    .endr
```

so maybe check your assembler if it supports such shortcuts.

> can I change the registry from r18 to r19 mid-loop?

No.  "Classic" AVRs could indirectly address general purpose registers, as they were mapped to memory addresses 0x0..0x1f, but I'd highly discourage such hacks.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `sbrc` way is worse because `sbrc` is slower, more than one cycle in some cases, unlike `bld`/`clr`/`bst`.  http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-BA59618D-4850-490B-B176-0BCC3D9438A1.html has a table of the instruction-set with timings.

Comment: *"Classic" AVRs could indirectly address general purpose registers* - did that change in other AVR models?  (I only know about AVR from casual interest and SO questions, as an interesting example of a RISC ISA that's different from most.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: `sbrc` and `sbrs` take 1 cycle if they don't skip, 2 cycles if they skip a 1-word instruction (and 3 cycles if they skip a 2-word instruction).  Thus, the timing is the same because "sbrx+1-word-insn" always takes 2 cycles. The indirect addressing of GPRs via their memory address is only available if SFR range starts at 0x20. If SFRs start at 0x0 (like with Xmega), there is no GPR mapping to memory address space.

Comment: Oh right, if it skips then fewer total instructions need to execute.  derp.  The table I found listed it as sometimes costing 3 cycles, though.  Cost of "1 / 2 / 3" on  AVR, AVRxm, or AVRxt, but not AVRrc where it's just 1 / 2.  A hypothetical superscalar AVR would do better with the bst / bld version.  But the `sbrc` way might save power from fewer memory fetches, especially if the code is in an external ROM, if that's a thing with AVR?

Comment: Dunno if there are AVRs with external code memory / interface.  There are AVR's with up to 384 KiB of flash. If that's not enough, maybe switch to some other arch, because memory segmentation (both ROM and RAM) will become more and more annoying.